# Reading JSON files from a folder and saving them as numpy arrays in a list

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read a folder that has multiple .json files in them. I want to convert each file into numpy array. This is my code

```
labelarray = []
for filename in glob.glob(r'C:/Users/samin/Desktop/Wolution/Datastets/Grass/label/*.json'):

    json_img = json.load(filename)
    numpy_2d_arrays = np.array(json_img)
    labelarray.append(im2arr)
```

but I get an error:

```
File "<unknown>", line 1
    C:/Users/samin/Desktop/Wolution/Datastets/Grass/label\Fuji V1 B1 24.05.json
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea what causes this error. 
Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: That error aside, you shouldn't be using `ast.literal_eval` for JSON, there is a json module for that.

Comment: I just changed it to json.load(filename) and now get another error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: You still need to open the file first

Comment: @parastoo91 You need to use `json.load(open(filename))`

Comment: I added: json_img = json.load(open(filename, 'r')) and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try it without the preceding `r` on the string. I'm a bit stumped at why this is a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Note: the array's `dtype` will be `object` if the list elements are dictionaries and not simple ones